# cant figure out logic for checking(using pyspellchecker) if a word is a word do one thing and if not do another using python

Tags: python, pyspellchecker

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
spell = SpellChecker()
user_words = ""
check_spelling = spell.unknown(user_words)
```

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

  

  if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
      user_text = ""
    if spell.correction(f"{check_spelling}") == None:
      user_text =""
    elif spell.correction(f"{check_spelling}") != None:
      user_text = "That's not a word, try again."
```

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'lightskyblue3', input_rect)    
screen.blit(text_Surface, (input_rect.x+5, input_rect.y+5))
input_rect.w = max(100, text_Surface.get_width()+10)
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)  # limits FPS to 60
```

I tried having the user text change back to normal if they put in a word, and if they put in a random letter or not a word it should say "That's not a word, try again".

Comment: I can't figure out what is your actual question.  Please edit the question to show us the **actual output** from this code, and explain how that's different from what you **wanted**.

Comment: Also, what do you mean "if they put in a word"?  There's no place in this code that accepts user input at all.

Comment: the output was always "thats not a word try again"

Comment: As a debugging step, print the output of `spell.correction()` to see what it actually returns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.